# Did people who were not priests ever enter the Tabernacle?

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle

Is there any mention in the Tanakh of people who were not priests entering the Tabernacle?

[Leviticus 17:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.17.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0) says that the people were to bring their sacrifices to the priest at the entrance of the tent of meeting. Is this the entrance to the courtyard? Did the people ever actually enter the courtyard of the Tabernacle? Was there any specific law about this?

I am especially interested in references to the Tanakh, but would also be interested in answers based on other Jewish texts.

I am secondarily interested in the related question of what parts of the Temple, if any, people who were not priests were allowed to enter, or did enter.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Lee, and thanks for your question. Hope you continue to contribute. :)

Comment: Regadring people who entered inner places - 
Uzziah [Chronicles 26,16+](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b26.htm#16)                                   Ezrat Nashim--Ezrat Israel--Ezrat Cohanim--U'lam--Heicahl--Kodesh Hakodashim. Israelites were allowed to enter up to Ezrat Israel (Women up to Ezrat Nashim)  
A little hard for me with translation, does 'Tabernacle' refer to the object or area?

Comment: They had to come inside to do Semikha (leaning) on the offering (in cases where doing so is prescribed).

Comment: @Zeev: Thanks for your comment. The story in 2 Chronicles 26:16-21 is a fascinating one! However, Uzzia's infraction seems to have been his intent to offer incense on the altar of incense rather than simply entering the temple.

Comment: @Double AA: Thanks. Can you provide some references in the Tanakh or other Jewish literature to this being commanded and/or done?

Comment: @LeeWoofenden - You have "tabernacle" in the title, but end the question with a reference to "temple", so you appear to be conflating the two. Is this deliberate? or is your interest explicitly in *either* "tabernacle" *or* "temple"? "Scholarly sources" will certainly distinguish them.

Comment: @Davïd Thanks. I understand that the Tabernacle and the Temple are two distinct structures. As stated in the question, I am primarily interested in an answer with regard to the Tabernacle. But I am secondarily interested in an answer to the same question with regard to the Temple, which might throw some additional light on the primary question.

Comment: Hi All: Thanks for the two answers so far, which do provide an initial "yes" answer to my question. What I would most love to see, and what would be a shoo-in for the bounty, would be an answer about whether people other than priests entered the Tabernacle *for ritual purposes.* @DoubleAA hinted at such an answer in the third comment above. If anyone can elaborate on that sort of answer, and show from the Tanakh and/or early Jewish writings that non-priests did or did not enter the Tabernacle in connection with sacrifices and offerings, that would get to the heart of my question. Thank you!

Comment: I should add that there was a mistake in my original question--a mistake that it's too late to fix, because answers have already been given and upvoted based on the original version. I should have asked whether people who were not priests *or Levites* ever entered the Tabernacle, especially for ritual purposes. If anyone is able to provide a solid, well-documented answer along the lines @DoubleAA suggested in his comment above (an answer that would still be well within the parameters of the original question), I would most likely mark that as the *accepted* answer. Thank you.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden, I recommend that you post a follow-up question that asks specifically and clearly what you are particularly interested in knowing, i.e. something along the lines of "Did anyone other than Priests and Levites enter the Tabernacle for ritual purposes?"

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thank you. I have now posted a new question [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59123/did-people-who-were-not-priests-or-levites-enter-the-tabernacle-for-ritual-purpo). I hope this one works better!

Answer (score 8):

How about Yoav ([Melachim I, 2:29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.2.29?lang=bi))?

He goes into "Ohel Hashem" (literally translated as Tabernacle in some places), and holds onto the "horns of the altar".  Yoav was not a cohen (relative of King David), and if I'm not mistaken, neither is the guy who is sent in after him (Binayahu Ben Yehoyada).

Also, in similar vein you've got Adoniah ([Melachim I 1:50](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.1.50?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), though it doesn't specify "ohel hashem" in that case.

Answer (score 7):

[Dafdigest](http://www.dafdigest.org/eruvin/Eruvin%20105.pdf) for Eruvin 105. I have extracted parts of the article which speaks about workers working *in the Temple* on

> the plating which was fastened on the walls of the Kodesh Kodoshim.
>   The inside walls of this special chamber were plated with gold panels,
>   which were attached to the walls by artisans and workmen (see Mishnah
>   Middos, 4:1,5). **If we do not
>   have a qualified kohen to do the job, we can use a Levi, or even
>   a Yisroel.** Instead of walking in via the route taken by the Kohen
>   Gadol who entered on Yom Kippur, these workers were lowered into the
>   Kodesh Kodoshim from the roof, enclosed in a special box which had a
>   small window in the side. When the box was lowered to the appropriate
>   position, the worker would open it and reach out to do his work.
>
> The mitzvah is that they enter in this suspended box, but, **if
>   necessary, the worker may even enter through the doorway** (see Tosefta,
>   Keilim 1:11). It is noteworthy that Rashi mentions that the gold
>   plates described in the Gemara were to be used for lining the walls of
>   the Kodesh Kodoshim. Yet, the words of the Baraisa brought by Rav
>   Kahana speak about these workers coming to the area —between the
>   antechamber and the altar. These workers were allowed in the holy
>   areas to bang and work the gold. In other words, not only did they
>   enter when it was necessary to fasten these plates, but they even came
>   in to work on them in the first place.   We see, surprisingly, that
>   although this work could have been done outside, yet, the workers were
>   allowed to enter the Mikdash and work inside, even in the area between
>   the altar and the Ulam.

Answer (score 5):

[Ⅱ Chronicles 35:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b35.htm#10) describes non-priest levites' slaughtering<sup>[1]</sup> and skinning sacrificial animals.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> according to [the commentary of *M'tzudas David*](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%90) inter alia